# How to calculate the real value in kb,mb,gb,b in Bash script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, unix

I want to convert all values with kb,mb,gb,b to the real bytes, for example, "10kb" should be convert to "10240" bytes.

Here is the test function:

```
#! /bin/bash

get_value_in_bytes()
{
    local value="$1"
    
    local unit_length=0
    local number_length=0
    local number=0
    
    if [[ "$value" == *"gb" ]]
    then
        unit_length=2
        number_length=$((${#value} - $unit_length))
        number=$((${value:0:$number_length})) * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 || -1
    elif [[ "$value" == *"mb" ]]
    then
        unit_length=2
        number_length=$((${#value} - $unit_length))
        number=$((${value:0:$number_length}))*1024*1024 || -1
    elif [[ "$value" == *"kb" ]]
    then
        unit_length=2
        number_length=$((${#value} - $unit_length))
        number=$((${value:0:$number_length}))*1024 || -1
    elif [[ "$value" == *"b" ]]
    then
        unit_length=1
        number_length=$((${#value} - $unit_length))
        number=$((${value:0:$number_length})) || -1
    else
        number=$((${value:0:$number_length})) || -1
    fi
    
    if (( $number < 0 ))
    then
        echo "error : $value"
    else
        echo "$number : $value"
    fi
}
```

Here is the test:

```
get_value_in_bytes 10kb
get_value_in_bytes 10mb
get_value_in_bytes 10gb
get_value_in_bytes 10b
get_value_in_bytes 10
get_value_in_bytes not_number_mb
get_value_in_bytes not_number_gb
```

Here is the output:

```
10*1024 : 10kb
10*1024*1024 : 10mb
./test.sh: line 15: test.sh: command not found
./test.sh: line 15: -1: command not found
0 : 10gb
10 : 10b
0 : 10
0*1024*1024 : not_number_mb
./test.sh: line 15: test.sh: command not found
./test.sh: line 15: -1: command not found
0 : not_number_gb
```

I want this function can accept any values as input, and if the value is not number string, then convert it to -1. But the above function doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Hint: spaces matter. Hint: quoting variables and strings usually solve weird issues related to unexpected shell expansions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution based on a bash ERE and a `case` statement:

```sh
get_value_in_bytes() {
    local bytes=-1
    if [[ $1 =~ ^([[:digit:]]+)(b|kb|mb|gb)?$ ]]
    then
        bytes=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        case ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} in
            kb) bytes=$((bytes * 1024)) ;;
            mb) bytes=$((bytes * 1048576)) ;;
            gb) bytes=$((bytes * 1073741824)) ;;
        esac
    fi
    printf '%s\n' "$bytes"
}
```

###### remarks:

- Shell arithmetic can only process integers. For floating point calculations you'll have to use an external tool like `bc`.
- The `b` unit is for `bit`. You should use `B` when you mean `byte`.
- Aside: the units based on `2^10` are `KiB` `MiB` `GiB` etc...

Comment: Nice! Suggest one level ident under the `case` statement. +1 tho

Comment: Added a POSIX-shell grammar vesion of your nice answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71903636/7939871

Answer (score 3):

As an illustration that using Bash's regex is not always necessary; here is [Fravadona's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71902802/7939871) rewritten using POSIX-shell grammar only:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

toBytes() {
  digits=${1%%[^[:digit:]]*}
  unit=${1##*[[:digit:] ]}
  case $unit in
    kb) bytes=$((digits * 1024)) ;;
    mb) bytes=$((digits * 1048576)) ;;
    gb) bytes=$((digits * 1073741824)) ;;
    b | '') bytes=$((digits)) ;;
    *) bytes=-1 ;;
  esac
  printf '%s\n' "$bytes"
}

for s in 10kb 10mb 10gb 10b 10 not_number_mb not_number_gb; do
  toBytes "$s"
done
```